# Python как отправить Post запрос с одинаковыми заголовками?

Tags: python, requests

Python как отправить данный Post/Get запрос с одинаковыми заголовками

```
import requests

url = 'http://'+input()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
origin = 'https://lol.com'
origin2 = 'http://example.com/'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,'Origin':origin,'Origin':origin2}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Comment: Какая конечная цель?

Comment: Чтобы на сервер пришло два заголовка origin с разными сайтами

Comment: Никто не знает,как это сделать)))

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_HTTP. *Заголовки с одинаковыми названиями параметров, но разными значениями могут объединяться в один, только если значение поля представляет из себя разделённый запятыми список. Во всех остальных случаях значения более дальних заголовков должны перекрывать предыдущие. Поэтому прокси-сервера не должны менять порядок следования заголовков в сообщении. При этом порядок элементов списка обычно значения не имеет.*

Comment: что за ресурс, который требует два заголовка origin?

Answer (score 1):

Вы используется dict для формирования заголовка, в нем нельзя использовать одинаковые ключи. В вашем случае это

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'a','Origin':'b','Origin':'c'}
print(headers)
```

выдаст `{'User-Agent': 'a', 'Origin': 'c'}`

Сформируйте строку вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте
`headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,'Origin':'origin,origin2'}`

UPD: В связи с комментарием

> так (кортежем или списком) - возможно, но не строкой 'origin, origin2' с
> запятой где-то посредине, как у вас в ответе

При попытке указать в headers кортеж или список или что-то еще, кроме строки или последовательности байтов

```
import requests

req = requests.Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/get')
req.headers['Origin'] = ('https://example.com', 'https://example2.com')
r = req.prepare()
print(r.headers)
```

В ответ получаем ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ruslan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 956, in check_header_validity
    if not pat.match(value):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: в headers['Origin'] будет строка 'origin, origin2', от этого два Origin в словаре не станет ;) вот так 'Origin': [origin, origin2] разве что?

Comment: Исхожу из того, что когда смотрю запросы в браузере, и вижу там например в headers
`x-frame-options
 DENY
x-frame-options
 SAMEORIGIN`
А в выводе headers в python это выглядит как:
`{'x-frame-options': DENY, SAMEORIGIN}`

Comment: так (кортежем или списком) - возможно, но не строкой 'origin, origin2' с запятой где-то посредине, как у вас в ответе